# Hibernate not generating proper insert statement after adding a new column

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

- For a table, I added a new column
- In hibernate mapping file, I ensured that, the new column is added
- But at runtime, hibernate is generating insert statement, which does not include the new column

For example,

old hibernate mapping definition:

```
<joined-subclass name="MyClass" extends="MySuperClass" table="tableName">
        <property name="propA" column="colA" />
        <property name="propB" column="colB" />
        <property name="propC" column="colC" />
        <property name="propD" column="colD" />
        <property name="propE" column="colE" />       
    </joined-subclass>
```

new hibernate mapping definition:

```
<joined-subclass name="MyClass" extends="MySuperClass" table="tableName">        
        <property name="propA" column="colA" />
        <property name="propB" column="colB" />
        <property name="propC" column="colC" />
        <property name="propD" column="colD" />
        <property name="propE" column="colE" />
        <component name="propF" class="compClass">
            <property name="compName"  column="colF" />
        </component>
    </joined-subclass>
```

Basically the insert statement is not taking colF into consideration.

Comment: add the code that creates and persirsts the enitty

Comment: I am using hibernate's session.save(entity)

Comment: ok.. how do you compose the entity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer the component class in entity class and populate component and then set in the main entity class like:

```
        Student student = new Student();
    student.setStudentName("HarKrishan");
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("HMR");
    student.setStudentAddress(address);
    session.save(student);
```

Comment: <class name="dao.entity.component.Student" table="STUDENT">
    <id name="studentId" type="long" column="STUDENT_ID"> <generator class="native" /> </id>
    <property name="studentName" type="string" not-null="true" column="STUDENT_NAME" />
    <component name="studentAddress" class="dao.entity.component.Address">
      <property name="city" column="ADDRESS_CITY" type="string" length="20" />
      <property name="state" column="ADDRESS_STATE" type="string" length="20" />
    </component>
  </class>